# Powershell - Delete files older dan x days but exclude folders

Tags: powershell

I have found a script on the internet, I have edited a little bit but it's not working

Using Powershell WS 2008 R2 Standard

Script is :

```
$del480 = "I:\CISS\Upload"
Get-ChildItem $del480 -recurse *.* -force | 
    where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-480)} | 
    Remove-Item -recurse
```

What I need is to add 4 folders to this script, that has to be excluded for deleting -480 days.
this are the folders:

```
I:\CISS\Upload\_Atest
I:\CISS\Upload\_Reporting
I:\CISS\Upload\_Templates
I:\CISS\Upload\_Upload files
```

Can somebody help me please ? Please keep in mind that I am not a script writer, I can read a little bit. But if you add a text something like add -exclude ......., than I don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this. You can do foreach-loops in your where to check against an array etc. The following is an alternative that only uses the pipeline.

Create an ignore-list of the paths, like this:

ignorelist.txt

```
I:\CISS\Upload\_Atest
I:\CISS\Upload\_Reporting
I:\CISS\Upload\_Templates
I:\CISS\Upload\_Upload files
```

Then try the following script

```
#I stored the date to avoid running it multiple times
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-480)
$del480 = "I:\CISS\Upload"
#Specify path for ignore-list
$ignore = Get-Content "C:\Ignorelist.txt"

Get-ChildItem $del480 -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $ignore -NotMatch | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line |
Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier, simpler, and safer to just use the ignore list to filter the Get-ChildItem in the first place?

Comment: I will test this, i will add all sub folders to the ignore list. Thank you for now.

Comment: I'm not saying you need to add every folder. It's just a warning that if you search from `.\Upload` , and you added `.\Upload\Folderone\Ignore` to the list, then `.\Upload\Folderone` would still be deleted(including all folders below).

Comment: @EBGreen , how ? `Get-childitem` doesn't support an array as filter, and `-exclude` only checks filename. The alternative to the solution above is as far as I know, to run through the ignore list in the where-statement, and I wanted to avoid this (since that is explained in 100 other posts here on SO)

Comment: I haven't tested it with folder names, but it does support arrays from the help: -Exclude <String[]>
    Omits the specified items. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt".
    Wildcards are permitted.

Comment: Nope you're right. Testing it with folders it does not exclude them. Shame.